# Android. How get of lost certificate

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, sha1

When my previous OS has broken and I installed new (it was 3 July), previous android_key_store.jks file was lost. (I was need save this file, but I saved only data for this certificate - keys, passwords). At new OS I created new android_key_store.jks file with ALL THE SAME keys, passwords (key store password, key alias, key password - all was the same like for  previous android_key_store.jks file).

Now I want to upload of update for app, but I have such error:

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: XXX ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: YYY ].

It's mean that previous and new certificate are different. Probably fo generating certificate used some random params (not only keys).

I tried to reestablish android_key_store.jks file from previous OS but I have fail.

How I can get previous certificate? (I remember all keys, passwords and data (name, organization) for this). Or it's impossible update this app and I need create new app at market?

I really need update current app.

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470183/i-lost-my-keystore-i-cant-upgrade-my-app-in-the-market?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271579/lost-original-keystore-android-app-eclipse?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843973/lost-my-keystore-only-have-sha1-from-it?rq=1 and countless others have already covered this. Restore your keystore from your computer backup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck, my friend.  Unless you can recover your old key store, you will need to upload a new version to the Play store.

See the Google Docs on App signing, particularly the segment on [Manage your own key and keystore](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#self-manage):

> If you lose access to your app signing key or your key is compromised,
>   Google cannot retrieve the app signing key for you, and you will not
>   be able to release new versions of your app to users as updates to the
>   original app.